# Can blob recored by MediaRecorder in 'audio/webm;codecs=opus` be played directly?

Tags: audio, google-chrome-extension, webm, opus, web-mediarecorder

I'm writing a chrome extension that simply records audio from a tab and sends to my local server.

> From my understanding, MediaRecorder in chrome extension is just same as the one in html.

```js
chrome.tabCapture.capture({ audio: true }, stream => {
  try {
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "audio/webm;codecs=opus" });
    recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', async (event) => {
      const request = new Request("http://localhost:3000");
      try {
        await fetch(request, { method: "POST", body: event.data });
      } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
      }
    });
    const timeslice = 2 * 1000;
    recorder.start(timeslice);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return;
  }
});
```

The local server is just for saving it as a file. I downloaded the file and played it, but it said the file was crashed. Forgetting about sending/downloading, what I did is just saving the blob from MediaRecorder to a file. But it was crashed. Do I need to do something more?

> Indeed, first I was trying to streaming the audio captured in a chrome tab to a server, but streaming was failed, of course. I thought that concatenating blobs in 'audio/webm;codecs=opus' didn't work because the webm file format didn't allow it. Is there any way to build a streamable blob in 'audio/webm;codecs=opus' blob from segments?